# MFMailComposer view does not suit with the color theme of my app

Tags: iphone, view, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Does anyone know how can we send mail without presenting the MFMailComposerView?

OR

Is there any way I can add a background image on the MFMailComposerView?

I tried changing the backgroud color. it doesn't work.
Only thing i could do was change the navigationBar Tint color

Code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
picker.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
picker.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the apple documentation:

> **Important:** The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, or even if possible, it would be probably rejected by AppStore.